# The method urllib.urlopen python 2.x does not work in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following line of code

```
sock = urllib.urlopen (url)
```

This line works perfectly in python 2.x, but when I run it with python 3.x it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python 3.x you should write like this:

```
import urllib.request
sock = urllib.request.urlopen (url)
print (sock.read (200))
```

In python 2.x: urllib.urlopen
In python 3.x: urllib.request.urlopen

print (sock.read (200)) displays the first 200 bytes of the contents of 'url'

Finally close the connection:

```
sock.close
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x, the `urllib.urlopen` function was moved to [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen):

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> urlopen
<function urlopen at 0x020BF4B0>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use `urllib.request.urlopen`